# How to solve these simultaneous equations using numerical methods?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

How to solve these simultaneous equations for $\alpha$ and $\lambda$ using numerical methods?

$\lambda * [(\frac{3}{4})^\frac{-1}{\alpha} - 1] = 11$

$\lambda * [(\frac{1}{4})^\frac{-1}{\alpha} - 1] = 85$

I am new to this. I tried resolving this using log. But, I could not solve it algebraically.

Comment: The obvious thing to do is first re-write it so the RHS is the 0 vector, and then use Newton's method to solve the non-linear system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's denote $\beta = -\frac{1}{\alpha}$. Next, divide the equations to get rid of $\lambda$:
$$
\frac{1 - \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^\beta}{1 - \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^\beta} = \frac{11}{85}
$$
Let's simplify things by multiplying by the denominator
$$
1 - \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^\beta- \frac{11}{85}\left(1 - \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^\beta\right) 
\equiv
\frac{74}{85} - \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^\beta + \frac{11}{85} \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^\beta 
= 0
$$
To simplify further, let's introduce $x = \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^\beta$, so 
$\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^\beta = x^{\log_{1/4} 3/4}$. Let the $A \equiv \log_{1/4} 3/4 \approx 0.2075187496$. Back to the equation
$$
F(x) = 74 - 85x^A + 11x = 0
$$
Plotting that function shows tho roots $x = 1$ and $x \approx 3$. The first one is spurious, introduced when we multiplied by the denominator. The second one is a true one.
Now the application of the Newton-Raphson method is straightforward.
$$
F'(x) = 11-85A x^{A-1}\\
x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{74 - 85x_n^A + 11x_n}{11-85A x_n^{A-1}}.
$$
First few iterations starting with $x_0 = 3$ yield
$$\begin{aligned}
x_0 &= 3.0000000000000000000,\\
x_1 &= 2.935098842008895510,\\
x_2 &= 2.93390459571424360,\\
x_3 &= 2.9339041802366199,\\
x_4 &= 2.933904180236570,\\
x_5 &= 2.93390418023657\end{aligned}
$$
Restoring original variables
$$
\beta = -\log_4 x_5 \approx -0.776410877\\
\alpha = -\frac{1}{\beta} = 1.28797783\\
\lambda = \frac{85}{4^{-\beta} - 1} \approx 43.95253956
$$

Answer (score 1):

We wish to solve the following system for $\lambda$ and $\alpha$
$$\lambda\left(\left({3 \over 4}\right)^{{-1 \over \alpha}} - 1\right) = 11$$
$$\lambda\left(\left({1 \over 4}\right)^{{-1 \over \alpha}} - 1\right) = 85.$$
We will then define
$$\textbf{f}(\lambda,\alpha) = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda\left(\left({3 \over 4}\right)^{{-1 \over \alpha}} - 1\right) - 11 \\ \lambda\left(\left({1 \over 4}\right)^{{-1 \over \alpha}} - 1\right) - 85\end{pmatrix}.$$
In order to solve the system by Newton's method, we follow the following algorithm

1. Choose an initial guess $\textbf{x}^{(1)}=(\lambda^{(1)},\alpha^{(1)})^T.$
2. Solve $J_{\textbf{f}}(\textbf{x}^{(k)})\textbf{d}^{(k)} = -\textbf{f}(\textbf{x}^{(k)})$, for $k=1,2,...$
3. Define $\textbf{x}^{(k+1)}= \textbf{d}^{(k)} + \textbf{x}^{(k)}$.
4. Repeat, until you have an acceptable solution.

Note that $J_{\textbf{f}}(\textbf{x}^{(k)})$ is the jacobian of $\textbf{f}$ evaluated at $\textbf{x}^{(k)}$.

Comment: I am trying Newton Raphson method. It is getting messy.

Comment: I tried programming it, but the jacobian is ill-conditioned, so no luck there. You may be able to use a fixed-point iteration method.

Answer (score 0):

At some point, you will have to take log since one of the unknowns is in the power.

An approach can be by dividing the two equations and cross-multiplying.